# More than one shortest paths from (s,t)

Tags: graph

My question is: suppose we have a directed graph

a->b (cost 4)
a->c (cost 2)

b->d (cost 1)

c->d (cost 3)

All edges have discrete costs.
And there are 2 paths from a to d that both cost 5.
There will be 2 shortets path trees or one?

The general question is: Suppose we have a directed graph, then the graph has a unique shortets path tree?

This is for an asignment.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia ([Shortest-path tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest-path_tree)):

> "...shortest-path trees in general are not unique."

Comment: Thank you a lot for your effort to answer this very simple question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there can be multiple shortest paths in a graph. 
In particular, you can use Djikstra's algorithm to compute shortest paths and this algorithm can return multiple paths from any node A to any other node B.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your effort to answer this very simple question too.

Answer (score 0):

They are not unique because it depends on the source vertex(for exp:like in dijsktra)